# MVC VaryByHeader User-Agent on All Actions for a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC website that serves up two different versions of the site for each URL (one for mobile, and one for desktop). I am trying to set the Responce.Cache.VaryByHeaders.UserAgent = true, but don't want to have to specify this on every single action in the controller, seems redundant. I would like to instead globally set if for all of the actions in a particular controller. Is this a reasonable thing to do? Where would I place the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use  [Action filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Sample from [howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public class CachingFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext 
    filterContext)
  {
    // set VaryByHeaders the way you need
  }
 }

 [CachingFilter]
 public MyController : Controller...
```